# Genesis 22:18 ‘the seed’ include the Moshiach?

Tags: tanach, messiah, abraham, king-david, genealogy

Genesis 22:18 speaks about Abraham’s descendants:

> וְהִתְבָּרְכוּ בְזַרְעֲךָ כֹּל גּוֹיֵי הָאָרֶץ עֵקֶב אֲשֶׁר שָׁמַעְתָּ
> בְּקֹלִי׃
>
> and in thy seed shall all the nations of the earth be blessed; because
> thou hast obeyed My voice.

Does the promise in Genesis 22:18 includes the future arrival of the Moshiach? Moshiach will be the direct descendant of King David who was from the lineage of Abraham (right?).

Comment: To answer your question about David being descended from Avraham, yes, although this isn't necessarily noteworthy for your point, as the Davidic lineage is one lineage from Abraham out of many many, including the non-Jewish descendants of Esau and Ishmael

Comment: the pasuk means that descendants of Avraham will be blessed, that means everyone. what do you mean by "include the arrival of moshiach"? Are you asking whether the moshiach is a descendant of Avraham?